# How to Display data on a Label using MS Access Database in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I tried to get the balance and customer name to show up on the labels by getting user's input the customers ID on textbox1. But every time i tried to input the ID even just the first digit of the ID, it already shows error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression".

```
                con.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE ID= '" +textBox1.Text+ "'";
                cmd.CommandText = sql;

                OleDbDataReader reader = null;
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    labelbalance.Text = reader["Balance"].ToString();
                    labelname.Text = reader["Firstname"].ToString() + reader["Lastname"].ToString();
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around Id:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE ID= " + textBox1.Text;
```

Because you have the quotes, ID is interpreted as character.

Update
As suggested in the comment, rather use parametrized query and avoid sql injection:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE ID= @var";
cmd.CommandText = sql;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@var", int.Parse(textBox1.Text));
```

Comment: ... or use proper parametrization and avoid being vulnerable to SQL injections...

Comment: thanks, the first solution work fine. i still dont get how parametrized query work since im still new to this but will try to learn it.

Comment: The parameter resolver looks for @variable and replaces it internally, in the process scrubbing and making sure there's nothing nefarious going on like little bobby tables.  When the command is submitted, the parameters are resolved internally and safely.  This is the _only_ way that SQL parameters should ever be handled: never concatenate a SQL string.  Cheers